# finding a particular getElementsByTagName('a') with a href that contains a domain

Tags: php, dom

I am using DOM to find all links at a particular URL that pertain to a specific domain. This script I have so far works great except it goes through every link on that page. What I would like to do to minimize overhead is to directly find any links `<a>` that contain part of a domain name so it only gets those links and ignores the rest.

`$anchors = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');` gets all the links, is there something I can do here to just get the links with a href that contains a url for instance `google.com` that way the rest of the script just focuses on those links?

```
$url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrabble";
$input = @file_get_contents($url) or die("Could not access file: $url");
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($input);
$anchors = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($anchors as $node) {
    echo $node->textContent;
    if ($node->hasAttributes()) {
        foreach($node->attributes as $a) {
            echo ' | '.$a->name.': '.$a->value;
            echo "<br>";
        }
        echo "<br><br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: What you're doing seems fine? You could probably target the anchors by partial attributes with XPath, but I'm not convinced it would be any faster, it still has to iterate over all anchors.

Comment: adeneo replied as I was typing the same thing.  just put an if statement in your current code to "continue" if the domain isn't what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use xpath to select only the desired items

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$anchors = $xpath->query("//a[contains(@href, 'google.com')]");    
// $anchors = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');
foreach($anchors as $node) {
```